# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get': AttributeError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, stripe-payments

I am getting error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get': AttributeError. PLease help me to figure out.

File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 15, in lambda_handler
create_stripe_customer(cardData,phone,email)

```
import json
import boto3
import stripe
client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
keys = json.loads(client.get_secret_value(
  SecretId = 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-so',
)['SecretString'])
public_key = keys['stripe-public']
secret_key = keys['stripe-secret']
stripe.api_key = secret_key
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cardData = event.get('cardData')
    phone = event.get('phone')
    email = event.get('email')
    create_stripe_customer(cardData,phone,email)
    return event

def create_stripe_customer(payment_info, phone, email):
    customer_id = stripe.Customer.create( phone = phone,email=email)['id']
    payment_method_id = create_payment_method(payment_info)
    stripe.PaymentMethod.attach(payment_method_id, customer = customer_id)
    return {"customer_id": customer_id,
            "plan": create_stripe_plan(customer_id)
    }

def create_payment_method(payment_info):
    return stripe.PaymentMethod.create(type = "card",
    card = {"number": payment_info.get('cardNumber'),
            "exp_month": payment_info.get('expirationMonth'),
            "exp_year": payment_info.get('expirationYear'),
            "cvc": payment_info.get('ccv'),
            }).get('id')      
        
def create_stripe_plan(customer_id):
    return stripe.Subscription.create(
        customer = customer_id,items = [{"plan": "plan_idxxxxxxx"}]).get("id")
```

Comment: What is the structure of `event`?

Comment: Please show where you are calling `lambda_handler`

Comment: I am calling it through aws api.

Comment: Are you using proxy integration in api gateway?

Comment: No I am not using proxy integration.

Comment: Also i am passing value in below format:        {
        "cardData": [{
            "cardNumber": "1234123412341234",
            "expirationMonth": "10",
            "expirationYear": "2025",
            "ccv": "123"
         }],
        "phone":"5464646",
        "email": "bijhasha@mit.com"
    }

Comment: The error & line reference don't make sense together. The referenced line does not have any `event.get()`. I imagine the issue with with event being undefined, but unclear why.

Comment: Actually this might be bubbling up from `create_payment_method` -- have you debugged how far this is getting before failing?

Comment: Yes..I think so because if i am using cardNumber or CVV instead of event.get('cardData'). It is working fine. The issue is how to accept all the parameters over single call.

Comment: I'd recommend breaking down the steps, ensuring you have the expected values at each step. See how far you get. If you get to the point of `paymentMethod.create()` it may be that you need to wait for a response before doing `.get('id')`

Comment: Ok .I got this.

Answer (score 0):

**Why it doesn't work**

`event.get()` may be the wrong type of call to be making to retrieve the data within event. As a result of this, the datatype would be collected and saved as `NoneType`.

> Referencing [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html), you can retrieve event items by calling event['item'] and not event.get('item').

**Here is an example:**

```py
def my_handler(event, context):
    message = 'Hello {} {}!'.format(event['first_name'], 
                                    event['last_name'])  
    return { 
        'message' : message
    }
```